# Highlight an background image with touch events(fingers) in android

Tags: android, imageview, touch, highlight, highlighting

I am new in Android and I'd like to know to highlight and image using touch event (using my finger). My approach is the next:

- App use a image that is used as background, it contains text to be highlighted.
- User highlight that image using his/her finger
- I don't like to write directly over the image. I'm thinking in something like "Layers".
- If is possible user should zoom the image because the image could be too large 5mp (the image is captured by the device camera)
- I don't like to save the layer that contains the highlight because I actually need is have coordinates to have a box that will be used to extract information from the background image.

I hope someone could help me.